# Why page call number of time when user come switching different pages in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-on

I am using jquery mobile.Actually my problem is the my page is call 3 time when user come switching from different pages .At first time my "Home" call one time.i add some data on data base using (+)button in header .it show in list view. But after clicking to row it show second page .on click the second page row it show third screen.while using back button it show second the again first .But again user press + button now page call three time .? why  it call three time i don't know?

here is my code in fiddle..
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/AkX7t/2/

```
<div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My Cases</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="headerButtons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                    <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                    <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog"id="Edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderData" >
                </ul>
                 <!--   Case Information Pop up-------------------------->
                <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none" style="max-width:300px !important; width: 300px !important" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                        <h1>Case Information</h1>
                        <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                    </div>

                     <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="caseNameValue" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Case Date:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="caseDate" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="caseTextArea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <!--   Case Information Pop up End-------------------------->

                  <!--   User setting Pop up-------------------------->
              <div data-role="popup" id="UserSettingScreen" data-close-btn="none" style="max-width:300px !important; width: 300px !important" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="CancelSettingButton">Cancel</a>
                <h1>User Settings</h1>
                <a href="#" ddata-role="button" data-corners="false">Ok</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                 <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">IP Address:</label>
                    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text"/>
                </div>  
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;">Display Font:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                        <option value="standard">A</option>
                        <option value="rush">B</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
             <!--   User setting Pop up End-------------------------->

            </div>

            <script>

                        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function() {

                       });

               </script>
        </div>


        <!-----------Document screen------------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="DocumentScreen" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
                <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >Back</a>
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My Documents</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <div><img src="img/Connect-Realtime.png" id="realTimeImaage"/></div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderInside_Data" >
                </ul>

            </div>

            <script>


                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#DocumentScreen', function() {
                console.log("init");
                 loadFolderContent();
                });
                        function loadFolderContent() {

                        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                        $('#folderInside_Data').append(
                          '<li class="rowID" id="' + i + '">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>Broken Bells</h2>' + '<p>Broken Bells</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + '</li>'
                                );
                        }
                        $('#folderInside_Data').listview('refresh');
                        }


                $(document).on('click', '.rowID', function() {
                      // $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"));
                $.mobile.changePage($("#realTimeScreen"), {
                transition: "pop",
                        reverse: false,
                        changeHash: false
                });
                    console.log(this.id)
                });</script>
        </div>
       <!-----------Document screen End------------------->

        <!-----------------------Real Time screen----------------------------->

        <div data-role="page" id="realTimeScreen" > 
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <a href="#DocumentScreen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Back</a>
                <h1 class="ui-title"  id="" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">Document name</h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a><img src="img/Follow-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Stop-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Email-Document.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Connect-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Manage-Case-Folders.png" id=""/></a>
                    <a><img src="img/Export-Realtime.png" id=""/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
                <div id="realTimeContents"></div>
            </div>
            <script>
         <!-----------------------add data Time screen----------------------------->
                for (i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                $('#realTimeContents').append(
                        '<span style="margin-left:5%;">' + 12.01 + '</span><span style="margin-left: 10%;">' + 'A' + '</span><span style="margin-left: 20%;">' + 'I was deputy canine devision' + '</span>' + '<br>'+ '<br>'+ '<br>'
                        );
                }
            </script>
            </div>


$(document).ready(function() {

                         $.mobile.loading('hide');
                         onDeviceReady();
                         });


$(document).bind('pagecreate', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'Home') {
        $("#headerButtons").on("click", "a", function() {

            if ($(this).attr("id") == "Add") {
                $('#caseNameValue').val('');
                $('#caseDate').val('');
                $('#caseTextArea').val('');
            } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Setting") {
            } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Edit") {
            }
        });

    }


    $(document).on('click', '.caseRowClick', function() {
        // $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"));
        $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"), {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: false
        });
        console.log(this.id)
    });


    $("#AddButton").click(function() {
        var isvalid = validationField();
        if (isvalid) {
            insertData();
            window.localStorage.setItem("isAddSomeData", "yes");
             $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"));
            /*$.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
            });*/
        }
    });


    $("#Cancel").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"));
        /*$.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
            transition: "pop",
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: false
        });*/
    });


    $("#CancelSettingButton").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"));
       /* $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"), {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: false
        });*/
    });

});

function validationField() {
    if ($('#caseNameValue').val() == '') {
        alert("Please Enter the Case Name");
        return false;
    } else if ($('#caseDate').val() == '') {
        alert("Please Enter the Case Date");
        return false;
    } else if ($('#caseTextArea').val() == '') {
        alert("Please Enter the Case Text Area");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var db = "";
//will create database Dummy_DB or open it

//function will be called when device ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Casepad", "1.0", "Casepad", 200000);
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("isAddSomeData") == "yes") {
        alert("Yes");
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }
    //   db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function insertData() {
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName TEXT NOT NULL,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('#caseNameValue').val() + '", "' + $('#caseDate').val() + '","' + $('#caseTextArea').val() + '")');
}

//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function successCB() {
    console.log("success!");
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

//select all from SoccerPlayer
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, result) {
    var len = result.rows.length;
    $('#folderData').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        $('#folderData').append(
                '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + i + '">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName + '</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + '</li>'
                );
    }
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly, this is a common **`jQuery Mobile`** problem with multiple event binding. Basically, depending on page events you are using, when you reopen some page all event bindings like click will be bound again. So you can have more then one click event on an object.

Best solution to handle this problem is, bind click and every other events (except page events, they don't suffer from this problem) **ONLY** like this:

```
$(document).off('click', '.caseRowClick').on('click', '.caseRowClick', function() {
    // $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"));
    $.mobile.changePage($("#DocumentScreen"), {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: false,
        changeHash: false
    });
    console.log(this.id)
});
```

In this case each time this click event is going to be bound, **`jQuery Mobile`** will first try to remove previous click even (if it exist) and then add a new one.

There are some other solutions to this problem and they can be found in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog. Just search for a chapter called: **Prevent multiple event binding/triggering**. This problem is described here with much more details + examples.